# Why does __get_cpuid return all zeros for leaf=4?

Tags: gcc, x86, cpu, intel, cpuid

I want to write a simple program which calls `__get_cpuid` to get the cache information:

```
#include <cpuid.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int leaf = atoi(argv[1]);

    uint32_t eax = 0, ebx = 0, ecx = 0, edx = 0;

    if (__get_cpuid(leaf, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx))
    {
        printf("leaf=%d, eax=0x%x, ebx=0x%x, ecx=0x%x, edx=0x%x\n",
                leaf, eax, ebx, ecx, edx);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First, I pass `leaf` as 2:

```
$ ./a.out 2
leaf=2, eax=0x76035a01, ebx=0xf0b2ff, ecx=0x0, edx=0xca0000
```

Since there is `0xff` in `ebx`, it means I can get cache info from `leaf=4` (refer [here](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm#level_0000_0002h)):

```
$ ./a.out 4
leaf=4, eax=0x0, ebx=0x0, ecx=0x0, edx=0x0
```

But this time, all return values are `0`. Why can't I get valid information from `__get_cpuid`?

Comment: Try using `__get_cpuid_count` which allows specifying the sub-leaf. I.e. `__get_cpuid_count(leaf, 0, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx)`.

Comment: @user786653 It works! Could you elaborate what's the difference between `__get_cpuid` and `__get_cpuid_count`? Why doesn't `__get_cpuid` work? Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the linked reference for EAX=4 we see that ECX needs to be set to "cache level to query (e.g. 0=L1D, 1=L2, or 0=L1D, 1=L1I, 2=L2)".

I couldn't quickly find any documentation on `__get_cpuid`, but a search did turn up the [soure code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3e5b5cb2a8a042fd3bb922313610e8672cdc2f93/gcc/config/i386/cpuid.h), where I noticed that you need to call `__get_cpuid_count` to have `ecx` set before the call to cpuid (otherwise you'll get random answers - mostly 0s it seems).

Comment: I assume you're getting all zeros because `ecx` holds garbage that's higher than the number of levels of cache your CPU has (maybe up to 4 on a CPU with eDRAM).  IIRC, that's how CPUID tells you you've enumerated the last level of cache.